# How to save bytes of binary file to React state? Or how else I can use AJAX with binary files?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Not sure what's the best practice for doing this. I need to send binary file (let's say a Excel's .xlsx) to the server without page loading. This is what I have now

```
var SendToServer = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <form action="/upload" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

I can grab this and process it further in my back-end so that's not the problem, but the HTML page will refresh and I don't want that. So I have to do this with AJAX and I've sketched something like this

```
var SendToServer = React.createClass({
  submit: function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/upload',
      data: {
        xlsx: ?
      }
      ...
    })
  }
  render: function(){
    return (
      <form action="/upload" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="button" onClick={this.submit} />
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

What to define in my data object? It seems to be that I can't just add `onChange` handler to my upload input like I would do with "normal" input field and though that save it to React's state.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this where the file can be accessed from the event handler. You don't necessarily need to save the file in the component's state.

```
var SendToServer = React.createClass({
  handleUpload: function(event) {
      var file = event.target.files[0];
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file',  file, file.name);

      $.ajax({
        url: "/upload",
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('Success!', data);
        },
        error: function() {
          console.error('Error uploading the file.');
        },
      });

    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleUpload} />
      );
    }
});
```